# Issue with validator function not setting error object on form control

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular2-forms, rxjs5

I have an issue with the following validator function:

```
export function validateEmailKnownFactory(userAccountService: UserAccountService): {[key: string]: any} {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return control
      .valueChanges
      .debounceTime(1000)
      .switchMap(value => userAccountService.checkAvailability(value))
      .map(res => {
        if (res.json() === false) {
          return null;
        }
        //Control flow does get through here
        return {emailKnownValidator: {unknown: true}};
      });
  };
}
```

It is not setting the error object (i.e. `{emailKnownValidator: {unknown: true}}`) on the form control but the control flow does get through the right place.

Now if I replace the above function with the following:

```
export function validateEmailKnownFactory(userAccountService: UserAccountService): {[key: string]: any} {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    return userAccountService.checkAvailability(control.value)
      .map(res => {
        if (res.json() === false) {
          return null;
        }
        return {emailKnownValidator: {unknown: true}};
      });
  };
}
```

the error object is set fine on the form control and the application behaves as expected.

Notice the difference: I get the `Observable` from `control.valueChanges` and I call `debounceTime` on it whereas the other function just call `checkAvailability` directly.

For completeness' sake here is the `checkAvailability` method:

```
  checkAvailability(email: string) {
    let body = 'email=' + email;
    return this.http.get(this.urls.USER_ACCOUNT.EMAIL_AVAILABLE + body);
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous validator functions in Angular 2 can return either a `Promise` or an `Observable`. If an `Observable` is returned, it must complete - as Angular [converts the `Observable` to a `Promise`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-rc.5/modules/%40angular/forms/src/validators.ts#L124-L134). That is, the `Observable` is used so that the validation can be asynchronous - not so that the validator can supply a stream of results.

The `Observable` composed from `valueChanges` in your first validator does not complete - as `valueChanges` keeps pumping out changes. That means the `Promise` doesn't resolve and there is no validation result that can be applied to the control. (Note that Angular will be calling your validation function for each change in the control's value and each call will see an `Observable` composed and subscribed to, so `checkAvailability` is going to be called for every change. The `debounceTime` operator is not going to effect the behaviour you seem to want.)

The `Observable` returned by the `checkAvailability` function does complete, so your second validator function works.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed explanation. There is one last point I would be grateful for you to clarify: do you mean to say that `debounceTime` won't achieve the effect I want is because the observable is "*subscribed to*"?

Comment: The conversion to a `Promise` is going to involve a subscription, but that's not really where the problem lies. It's that fact that a each call to the validator returns its own composed `Observable` that chains `valueChanges` to the HTTP-based `Observable` from `checkAvailability`, so each call is always going to see the latest change fed into `checkAvailability`. You could use `debounceTime` to compose an `Observable` to get the effect you want, but you cannot compose it inside the validator, as doing so will result in each call composing a separate `Observable`.

Comment: I hope that makes sense. It's getting a little late, here.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense.